# How do i store multiple data format in a QR code using "QR-tools" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code

[qrtools documentation](https://github.com/primetang/qrtools)

for example:

```
from qrtools import QR

#url
my_QR = QR(data = u"https://www.poemhunter.com/", 
                  data_type = 'url',pixel_size = 10)
```

> I want to store 2 data type i.e(Email and url) both in one QR code)

```
#email
#my_QR = QR(data = u"abcde@gmail.com.com",data_type = 'email',pixel_size = 10)

#encodes to a QR code
my_QR.encode()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to store two different data type in one QR Code. What is the purpose? Maybe a vCard is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Hoenie As of now qrtools is supported only on python 2. so i am using python 2.

Comment: @Pierre A example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vCard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) is format to store contact information. You can use it if you want to share the content of a visit card just with one QR Code.

In your example, if you want to share an email address and a website, you can put this text as data in your QR Code:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;
FN: 
ORG:
TITLE:
ADR:;;;;;;
TEL;WORK;VOICE:
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:john@doe.com
URL:http://john.doe.com
NOTE:
END:VCARD
```

As you can see, there are some missing values (I'm not sure if all the data are compulsory). You can also add the name, address, phone number, ...

I think its the best way to store multiple data format in one QR Code. You can find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-generating-qr-codes-python-using-qrtools/) an example to create a QR Code who contains a vCard with QRtools.

Comment: This in not what i am looking for. The main aim is to create a QR code with multiple data formats not just Storing Email and url. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @yajantb I'm not sure it's possible. What behavior do you expect when the user scans the code? Because this behavior depends of the data format: print a text if plain text, open a web browser if URL, open a mail client if email, ...

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just implemented v-card using datatype as phonebook and i succeed. I was trying to make a business card, where i was trying to store all data formats into one qr-code.

Comment: Can i make custom tags and store data in them within a qr-code?

Comment: @yajantb What do you mean by _custom tags_ ?